# How can I get new cloned item in jQuery Sortable receive function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm dragging new item to sortable list, but when I call ui.item it points to original object. How can I get reference to new dropped object?

Link to same problem in jQuery forum:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-receive-how-do-i-get-new-item

Comment: possible duplicate of [apply a javascript function to draggable copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741822/apply-a-javascript-function-to-draggable-copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [*update*](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-update) instead of *receive* to get a handle to the newly dropped object.

I've created a [**small demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mMmhw/1/) that changes the color of the dropped object to red after dropping. It does rely on the class name of the clone to differentiate between a received clone and an internal sort (otherwise everything would end up red after sorting).

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery UI 1.10 the way is this:

```
$('#sortable-list').sortable({
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    // New item
    var droppedItem = $(this).data().uiSortable.currentItem;
  }
});
```